# Read calendar java and print it again

Tags: java, string, date, calendar, format

I know that it's a repeated question, but I can not understand why this code is returning me this result. Maybe one of you can solve it quickly.

The question is: how to get a string to Calendar and after that, show it again to check if it's valid. The input string is

```
String time = "2015-01-05T09:20:07.532595Z";
```

And the code to transform it and print it is:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.GERMANY);
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse(time));

String splitted1 = time.split("T")[1];
String[] timeSplitted = splitted1.replace("Z", "").split(":");
Integer hour = Integer.parseInt(timeSplitted[0]);
Integer minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeSplitted[1]);
String s = String.valueOf(timeSplitted[2]);
String[] timeSplitted2 = s.split("\\.");
Integer seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeSplitted2[0]);
Integer ms = Integer.parseInt(timeSplitted2[1]);

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, ms);

System.out.println("[ORIGINAL]" + time);
System.out.println("[Result1    ]" + df.format(cal.getTime()));
System.out.println("[Result2    ]" + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + ms);

SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(formatted);
System.out.println(format1.parse(formatted));
```

The results is:

```
[ORIGINAL]2015-01-05T09:20:07.532595Z
[Result1    ]2015-01-05T09:28:59.000595Z
[Result2    ]9:20:7.532595
2015-01-05 09:28:59.000595
Mon Jan 05 09:28:59 CET 2015
```

I would apreciate all of your answers. I don't know if the problem is when I am showing the result or if the problem is in Calendar instance itself. I want to be sure that the variable cal is well parsed.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time string you should remove the nanoseconds. And amend the pattern accordingly.

```
    String time = "2015-01-05T09:20:07.532595Z";
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.GERMANY);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = df.parse(time.substring(0, 23)); // remove the nanoseconds
    cal.setTime(date);

    System.out.println("[ORIGINAL   ] " + time);
    System.out.println("[Result1    ] " + df.format(cal.getTime()));

    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.GERMANY);
    String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("[formatted  ] " + formatted);
    System.out.println("[parsed     ] " + format1.parse(formatted));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, ms)
```

value of ms is 532595 which when converted to minutes is 8 minutes 52 seconds approx, which is  the difference you see in Result1 and Result 2.

Try correcting this as :
`cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, ms/1000)`.

It works fine.